# Eloquent how to update deleted_at column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to soft delete the records and it working fine however my table `deleted_at` is showing null and the `updated_at` didn't record the latest date too. 
[image]

Code

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $record = Sale::findOrFail($id);

        if ($record->delete()) {
            return response()->json([
                'id' => $id,
                'success' => true,
            ]);
        } else {
            abort(404,'Sale not found.');
        }
    }
```

Model

My model already implemented

```
use SoftDeletes;
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

Migration

```
Schema::create('sales', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('ref_num', 50);
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

How to update the column `updated_at` and `deleted_at` with current time?

Comment: can you show a migration file with that table?

Comment: @V-K updated post

Comment: ok, seems good, I do not see the issue, maybe try to remove `protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];`, hope it can help

Comment: also for timestamps you can use `$table->timestamps();` It will add columns `created_at` and `updated_at`

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: @V-K Thanks for advice. I will try see

Comment: @user11622164 Laravel 7